# Ubuntu Bonding doesn't work on Dell R730

Tags: server, 20.04, network-bonding

I am unable to make a bond work on an R730 DELL server whereas r630 servers (we have 3) are connected to the same switch and have the same VLAN's allowed are working without any issues.I have cross checked again with my network guy and it is confirmed to have the same VLAN's on both the ports of the switches. I have tried breaking the bond and assigning the IP on the individual interfaces to see if the ping is happening, and indeed it works.
It's purely L2 and passed in access mode. Apparently, there is another bond in the same R730 and R630 servers, which works flawlessly, although the only difference, in this bond case, is the L3 layer, and it's in trunk mode.
I am not sure why the prior doesn't work with bonding in place, that too in R730. Am I missing something here? Can someone guide me here pls?

Here is the bonding config across all my R630 and R730 servers.(Bond0 passed with VLAN - which works, Bond1 with no vlan - doesn't work in R730 but works in R630)

Server OS - Ubuntu 20.04

```
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    bonds:
        bond0:
            interfaces:
            - enp130s0f0
            - enp3s0f0
            macaddress: b4:96:91:08:1b:7c
            mtu: 1500
            parameters:
                down-delay: 0
                gratuitious-arp: 1
                mii-monitor-interval: 100
                mode: active-backup
                transmit-hash-policy: layer2
                up-delay: 0
        bond1:
            addresses:
            - 100.20.20.230/27
            interfaces:
            - enp130s0f1
            - enp3s0f1
            macaddress: b4:96:91:08:1b:7e
            mtu: 1500
            parameters:
                down-delay: 0
                gratuitious-arp: 1
                mii-monitor-interval: 100
                mode: active-backup
                transmit-hash-policy: layer2
                up-delay: 0
```

Comment: Can somebody help here!

Comment: Alas!! i am without help.